# Insert a <li> inside an empty <ul> or to the bottom if <li> exists with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-lists

I had a look around and (strangely) couldn't find this being asked before, so apologies if this is a duplicate.

I have an unordered list with the class `.attachments`, if it has no list items inside of it I want the code to insert the `<li>` inside of the `<ul>`, if any `<li>` exists (regardless of how many) I wish for it to be inserted at the bottom before the `</ul>`. How would I go about doing this?

I have the following code, however this would apply it after the `</ul>` instead of inside of it.

```
$("ul.attachments").after('<li></li>');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `.after()`, use `.append()`:

```
$("ul.attachments").append($("<li>"));
```

There's no special case when there are no items inside the `<ul>`, you just always insert it at the bottom. That's how the DOM tree works.

Comment: Append works perfectly, thanks! I was trying appendTo, but had it in the wrong order.

Answer (score 1):

Append is the right method, you can also use prepend if you want to insert it before.

```
$('ul').prepend('<p>Test</p>');
$('ul').append('<p>Test</p>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the [Append](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method, no?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [appendTo](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).

Example:

```
<ul id="first">
</ul>
<ul id="second">
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test2</li>
</ul>

$("<li />", { text: "List item1" }).appendTo("#first");
$("<li />", { text: "List item2" }).appendTo("#second"); // Will be inserted after test2
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3ZZe7/)